# Is there any way to make Outlook Search Folders return archived emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My Outlook Search Folders (e.g. for all messages with a certain category) only show me messages that are in my main mailbox and not those that have been auto-archived because they're too old.  Is there a way to make them look in all mail (including the archive) the way you can with a regular search (i.e. one that you type in the search box)?

Unfortunately changing the auto-archive settings is not an option, so everything more than a year old will always be in the archive - but I want to be able to find these emails from my search folders as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which version of Outlook you're using but in Outlook 2010 you need to include the Archive PST in your indexing settings:

1. Open Outlook Options
2. Go to the Search section
3. Click on the 'Indexing Options...' button.
4. Click Modify
5. Find Microsoft Outlook
6. Hopefully your Archive.pst file is there, just make sure it's checked.